# (Objective C) NSPopUpButton not updating displayed value

Tags: objective-c, macos, nsview, nspopupbutton

I'm making a UI using an NSPopUpButton, passing it an array of strings and selecting an item by index. When this is then shown, it defaults to the first item. Can anyone see what I'm missing? DropDownView extends an NSView.

```
@implementation DropDownView

- (id)initWithFrame: (NSRect)frameRect
             values: (NSArray<NSString*>*) vals
            current: (NSInteger) currentIndex
{
    [super initWithFrame:frameRect];
    menu = [[NSPopUpButton alloc]initWithFrame:frameRect pullsDown:NO];

    [menu addItemsWithTitles:vals];

    [menu setEnabled:true];

    // this does not change the currently displayed value
    // have tried various combinations of the below
    [menu selectItemAtIndex:currentIndex];
    // [menu selectItemWithTitle:vals[currentIndex]];
    [menu synchronizeTitleAndSelectedItem];

    [self addSubview:menu];

    [menu bind:@"selectedIndex" toObject:self withKeyPath:@"indexOfSelectedItem" options:nil];

    return self;
}
@end
```

many thanks!

Comment: does call `addSubview:` right after `[[NSPopUpButton alloc]initWithFrame:frameRect pullsDown:NO];` and before `selectItemAtIndex:` helped?

Comment: Shouldn't the first statement be `self = [super initWithFrame:frameRect];` followed by `if (self) {`.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you bind selectedIndex, the selectedIndex of menu is set to self.indexOfSelectedItem. Don't call selectItemAtIndex and synchronizeTitleAndSelectedItem and set indexOfSelectedItem to currentIndex.

Comment: thanks, my silly error. think the bind was the problem. got rid of the menu calls and instead just changed the bound value after it was bound using the kvo setters, made it work as expected.